# Java Server-Side screen resolution detection

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, server

I'm building my own HTTP server in java, but i'm facing with a problem: I would like to build a page dynamically by creating every HTML object at runtime, the question is: how can i determine the screen dimension of the client's browser?

This information is not present in the HTTP header, so I was thinking about writing a "fake" webpage that runs a javascript that tells the server about the screen (it should redirect to something like www.website.com/w:1920,h:1080) but I don't know anything about cookies (that I suppose are essential to store those informations).
Do you think that I should learn somthng about cookies or there's another way?
BTW I'm not using servlets, just Socket, because that's what I know... should I use servlets?
Thanks for your time!

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

Server knows nothing about client's screen until client send this information. Javascript is easiest way to determine screen size:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

AJAX request can be used to send the information to the server where it can be stored in session data and backed in database for example if the user is logged in or identified somehow. In such case you don't need cookies. However solution with cookies is easier, check how to set them via javascript. But I'm afraid such solution would be a bit of non-standard, if your site is gonna depend on javascript why not to use it extensively and generate all objects on client side, get that lazy computer working and save your server's resources :) Just feed data by sending simplest HTML containing script doing the work.

Servlets? Can be really light-weight and done with minimal knowledge if you have time go for it.

Comment: Well, I'm amazed by how much I can do with my own server, managing the connections, generating HTML at runtime... This website used to rely on JS, but it was the less dynamic thing ever eheheh.<br>I think I'm going with the cookie solution